# Use __getattribute__ to run a pre-command hook and continue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to set a class state variable before running any class methods every time I call a method; is there a way to use `__getattribute__` to run a pre-command hook and continue on to the `attr` specified? Would I have to use a `metaclass`, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this using `__getattribute__` you could do something like this.

```
import inspect

class A:
    def __getattribute__(self, attrname):
        attr = super().__getattribute__(attrname)
        if inspect.ismethod(attr):
            # Do state stuff
        return attr
```

Instead of using `__getattribute__` you could also create a decorator function that does the state stuff you want to do, and add that to each method you want it to apply to.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks! I'd make a decorator, but I'd like this action to be the default, so there would be too many methods to use the decorator on.